# I can't print the list on the screen

Tags: javascript, json, excel

I want to list my json data as checkboxlist. I wrote this code. I'm printing this way. I don't know where I'm doing wrong. I get my jSON data from excel file. textarea comes out as "undefined undefined" .  Could you help?

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="example">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
  </form>

  <textarea 
    id="data" 
    class="form-control text-area-style" 
    rows=35 
    cols=120>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

JS CODE:

```
function ExcelToJSON() {
  var list;
  document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
  this.parseExcel = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: "binary"
      });
      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          list = JSON.parse(json_object);
          console.log(list);
          jQuery().val(json_object);

          list.forEach(function() {
              $('#data).append(' < input name = "accesories"
                type = "checkbox"
                value = "'+list.id+'" / > '+list.name+' < br / > ');
              });
          })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };

  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.forEach(function() {
              $('#data).append(' < input name = "accesories"
                type = "checkbox"
                value = "'+list.id+'" / > '+list.name+' < br / > ');
              });
          })
```

list does not have the attributes id and name (are undefined), you are iterating over list but you are **not using the iterated item**.

```
list.forEach(function(item) { // <= forEach calls for every list item this function with the item as argument
              $('#data).append(' < input name = "accesories"
                type = "checkbox"
                value = "'+item.id+'" / > '+item.name+' < br / > ');
              });
          })
```

**Hint:**
Use the build in Browser Debugger it helps a lot, to understand JS.

With Chrome press F12 and set a breakpoint in the foreach function, then execute your code and it will break on the given line, then you will see all variables in your scope. (In your case you will se that list is an array and don't have id and name as property)